# Reflection to make DTO objects in WCF

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, reflection, dto

I was wondering if I could find out the difference in performance from others experience with reflection and DTO objects inside a WCF service. I have the code below that I was using to create a DTO object from an Entity object using Linq.

```
   using (dashEntities context = new dashEntities())
        {
            result = context.GetAlerts().Select(m => new AlertItemDTO()
            {

            }).ToList();
```

Another programmer when building their WCF Service wrote a Generic method using Reflection to do the same conversion:

```
private object TransferEntityToDTO(object dto, object entity)
    {
        Type entityType = entity.GetType();

        // Use reflection to get all properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in entityType.GetProperties())
        {

            if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {

                List<PropertyInfo> dtoProperties = dto.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

                foreach (PropertyInfo dtoProperty in dtoProperties)
                {

                    if (dtoProperty.Name == propertyInfo.Name)
                    {   

                        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity, null);

                        if (value != null && value.ToString() != "" && value.ToString() != "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
                        {
                            // This section gets the type of of the property and casts
                            // to it during runtime then sets it to the corresponding 
                            // dto value:

                            // Get current class type
                            Type currentClassType = this.GetType();

                            //Get type of property in entity object
                            Type propertyType = Type.GetType(propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName);

                            // Get the Cast<T> method and define the type
                            MethodInfo castMethod = currentClassType.GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);

                            // Invoke the method giving value its true type
                            object castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });

                            dtoProperty.SetValue(dto, value, null);

                        }
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return dto;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used in TransferEntityToDTO to dynamically cast objects to
    /// their correct types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to cast object to</typeparam>
    /// <param name="o">Object to be casted</param>
    /// <returns>Object casted to correct type</returns>
    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
```

Obviously, the second technique is harder to read and more lengthy, but it is more generic and could be used in multiple services.

My Question is, does the ability to make it generic outweigh the performance hit from using reflection and if not, why? I found a lot of confusing articles and answers to what makes reflection expensive. I assume part of it is because it needs to look for the object it needs without already knowing, kind of like using the Generic Exception for everything when you know the exception you will get.

Can someone shed some light on this for me please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between these two solutions is that the first uses a projection and the second maps the original entity. For entities that are only a small subset of the original entity (e.g. dtos for lists) it should always be faster to query only the projected properties instead of the complete entity (perhaps with nested entities and properties you don't need...), which is then mapped to the dto.

To combine the advantages of both solutions (projection + generic solution) you could automagically create projection expressions, cache them and use them within a *Select(Expression<...>)* call like in your original solution. So all mappings are only created once, you get your dtos directly and only neccessary columns are queried. Have a look at this article and the comments: [Stop using AutoMapper in your Data Access Code](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code).

AutoMapper can also build mapping expressions, but it will only map simple properties (as far as I understood it from the source code). With a custom solution and some 'expression magic' you could also support complex mappings that are then translated to sql by entity framework:

```
ContactName = Contact.Name,
AddressStreetAndNumber = (Address.Street + (" " + Address.Number)).Trim()
```

This code [here on github](https://gist.github.com/1119157) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at some of the popular open source mapping libraries like AutoMapper, EmitMapper, or ValueInjecter, you'll see that they don't use the reflection method any more, instead they use things like [compiled expression trees and IL generation to speed things up](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/08/05/analyzing-automapper-performance/).

Obviously that makes them more complicated internally (they are still very easy to use) than the basic reflection based mapper, but as usual, optimizing for speed adds complexity.

My opinion is that you should use one of these (excellent) open source libraries where the authors have spent tons of time considering many questions just like yours.

Comment: Thank you for your insight as I was unaware of this library and other like it that have already taken these things into account. For now, due to lack of time to test it out and others like it, I would like to stick to these two scenarios to see which is better to use? At least for now and then over the next few months, test and bring in these new libraries

Comment: @gcoleman0828: I suggest that you do not roll your own solution and use the libraries instead. They are complex only under the hood but are actually very easy to use. They're also well tested and offer great performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some lightweight ORMs will be helpful. For example [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [Petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/).
They can bind result of SQL query to dynamic or static object by using IL (Emit)